# How can I pass a parameter to expire jobs in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I want to achieve a functionality where sidekiq job is expired if not processed within a certain time. How can the same be achieved?

I got one options as passing "expires_in" as parameter with Sidekiq-pro. Any other way same can be achieved?

Comment: Can you be more precise or give some actual code ? Because a Sidekiq  job is basically a worker being called. Once the worker is called your Sidekiq process succeeds or fail. I don't see a possibility for the worker to just hang ... A very time consuming calculation maybe ? Please give more info

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for replying. Issue is that sidekiq workers has a huge list of jobs to process in different queues having different priority.If job is not processed once it is inside a low priority queue within a minute, we tend to reprioritize
the same and create a new entry in higher queue. At this moment I know that job is still existing in lower queue. Wanted to delete the entry from lower queue at this moment so that accumulation of jobs could be avoided.